# ¿Porque al insertar un InputStream no muestra nada?

Tags: java, mysql, web

Tengo un servlet donde llamo un input tipo file que trae una imagen, la cual quiero insertar a la base de datos. El problema es que si lo hago con una variable tipo InputStream no me inserta nada en el campo imagen, lo intento asi:

```
 Part pt = request.getPart("txtImagen");
 String tipo = pt.getContentType();
 InputStream inS = pt.getInputStream();
 p.setImg(inS);
 p.setDescripcion(request.getParameter("txtDesc")+" y su tipo es: "+tipo);
```

Me dijeron que quizás podria ser el tipo asi que probe insertar un bytearray y si insertaba pero al parecer no es mi archivo porque difiere mucho del tamaño original de la imagen, luego probe convirtiendo ese byteArray a hexString, pero obtuve el mismo resultado, lo hice de esta forma:

```
Part pt = request.getPart("txtImagen");
String tipo = pt.getContentType();
InputStream inS = pt.getInputStream();
byte[] b = toByteArray(inS);
String hex = bytesToHex(b);
p.setImg(hex);
p.setDescripcion(request.getParameter("txtDesc")+"Y su tipo: "+tipo);
```

Y estos son los metodos toByteArray y bytestoHex que uso para convertir:

```
//Metodo para convertir InputStream a biteArray
    public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
 
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
 
        // read bytes from the input stream and store them in buffer
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            // write bytes from the buffer into output stream
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
 
        return os.toByteArray();
    }
    //Metodo para convertir byteArray a Hex
    private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

A continuación dejo las inserciones que hice a la base de datos probando las distintas formas que mencione:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los 3 registros fueron insertados con la misma imagen, el primero lo hice manualmente desde phpMyadmin, los otros dos desde mi aplicación java web. Cabe recalcar que si tengo la anotacion `@MultipartConfig`  y el formulario donde esta el input tiene la propiedad `enctype="multipart/form-data`. No se si sea porque uso phpMyadmin con xampp.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda de ante mano!

Comment: Supongo que *p* es un *PreparedStatement* con un INSERT, ¿cierto? (estaría bien ponerlo, con el SQL). En todo caso me extraña que en los registros que muestras, en un caso determine el tipo bien y en el otro no, ya que la lógica para obtener el tipo es la misma en los dos códigos. ¿Estás seguro de que no hay otra cosa que estés cambiando entre las dos pruebas?